# Conditionally applying JsonConverter

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I have a data structure we use to make api update calls to TFS and we set the Value property as a generic which works well. We'd like to use enums in our client code as representations of some types but they serialise as integers. So there is the `[JsonConvert(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` option, on a generic this is an issue as it tries to serialise all values as string against the enum type of the property. It looks like this:

```
public class WorkItemUpdateData<T> : WorkItemUpdate
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to conditionally apply the converter when the property T is enum only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By implementing a custom converter and specifying this as the converter:

```
public class OnlyEnumStringConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value != null && value.GetType().IsEnum)
        {
            base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
        }
        else
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (objectType.IsEnum)
        {
            return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        }
        else
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }
    }
}
```

Specifying it:

```
public class WorkItemUpdateData<T> : WorkItemUpdate
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(OnlyEnumStringConverter))]
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you do `CanConvert(value.GetType())` and `CanConvert(objectType)` you will be able to handle nullable enum types as well.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Just gotta work out how to unit test it now.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be easier to "sideclass" this, have a WorkItemUpdateData and a WorkItemUpdateEnumData ? Then your conditional logic to have the JsonConverter apply can be made when creating the object rather than when serializing it.

```
public class WorkItemUpdateData<T> : WorkItemUpdate
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class WorkItemUpdateEnumData<T> : WorkItemUpdate
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

You could also include something in the setters to ensure they're used correctly, like

```
if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw ...
```

Comment: You specified the JsonConverter attribute in the wrong class I think. Can you check that?

Comment: @OguzOzgul could have done mate, I wasn't clear from the question what each bit did exactly and I don't have a project to test it on. I just presumed the point would get across and the OP would adapt to suit their needs :)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Only problem the calling code needs to not have to care which subclass to use.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest the other answer from @OguzOzgul would be the only way to go. You really have to either change the callers to know the right converter, or change the converter to understand the data. With it decorated on the property it's going to run always and there's no way around that, you need to work out which way to roll with that punch.